# How to prove $(3^b \mod 17)^a \mod 17 = 3^{(ba)} \mod 17$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I watched this 2min video https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modern-crypt/v/diffie-hellman-key-exchange-part-2 and I am struggling on understanding the proof in a comment (@Cameron) below.

Basically, the author firstly proves that:

- $(x * y) \mod z = (x \mod z) * (y \mod z) \mod z$

Then he uses this to prove $(3^b \mod 17)^a \mod 17 = 3^{(ba)} \mod 17$ .

But I just can't understand one of the steps and really doubt it:

He writes:

1. $3^{(ba)}  \mod 17 = 3^{(ba)} \mod 17$
2. $3^{(ba)} \mod 17 = (3^{b(a-1)} * 3^b ) \mod 17$
3. $3^{(ba)} \mod 17 = (3^{b(a-1)} \mod 17) * (3^b \mod 17) \mod 17$
4. $3^{(ba)} \mod 17 = (3^{b(a-2)} * 3^b \mod 17) * (3^b \mod 17) \mod 17$
5. $3^{(ba)} \mod 17 = (3^{b(a-2)} \mod 17) * (3^b \mod 17) * (3^b \mod 17) \mod 17$

From 4. to 5. ,

$(3^{b(a-2)} * 3^b \mod 17) * (3^b \mod 17) \mod 17$ should have decomposed to

$[(3^{b(a-2)} \mod 17) * (3^b \mod 17)  \mod 17 ] * (3^b \mod 17) \mod 17$ .

I don't know why he drops the $\mod17$ and I think it can't be dropped.

I've been thinking this for hours and sorry if I didn't get the format right.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in`$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: @saulspatz Any tools recommended to format the formula? I will go format the post right away.

Comment: Your notation is ambiguous.  What do you mean by $3$^b^a ?  Use parentheses if you can't figure out how to format properly.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Be care with `3^a^b.` That is usually taken to mean $3^{(a^b)}$ but here you want $(3^a)^b.$

Comment: Post edit, what you are asking is false.  Take $b=1$.  Then $3^{(b^a)}=3$.  But $\left(3^1\right)^a=3^a$.

Comment: This result is implied by the general Number Theory result that $(a + nk)^r \equiv a^r \pmod{n}.$  The result is immediate from the binomial expansion, where all but the first term have a factor of $(n)$.  Here, you have that $17 ~| ~\left\{(3^b) - [\text{the } ~\pmod{17} ~\text{residue of } ~(3^b)]\right\}.$

Comment: @user2661923 Could you make that a little bit easier to understand? And so the original proof from 4. to 5. is wrong?

Comment: Normally, I would say that you want $\left(3^b\right)^a = 3^{(a\times b)}.$  My inference is based on the idea that you want the exponents on both sides to be identical.  If this is incorrect, it invalidates my previous comment.

Comment: Assuming that you want $\left(3^b\right)^a$, so that the exponents on the LHS and RHS are identical, you have that $(a + nk)^r = a^r + \binom{n}{1} a^{(r-1)}(nk)^1 + \cdots + \binom{n}{n-1}a^1(nk)^{(r-1)} + (nk)^r.$  In the RHS summation, $n$ divides all but the first term.

Comment: Again, it is not true for $3^{(b^a)}.$ It is true for $(3^b)^a.$

Comment: Further, you have that $(3^b)$ may be re-expressed as $\{[3^b] \pmod{17}] + 17k\}.$

Comment: The assertion holds for $\left(3^b\right)^a = 3^{(b\times a)}.$  In general, you do **not** have that $\displaystyle 3^{\left(b^a\right)} \equiv \left(3^b\right)^a \pmod{17}.$  Therefore, if the RHS of the conjecture intends $\displaystyle 3^{\left(b^a\right)}$ rather than $\left(3^b\right)^a$, then the conjecture will not always be true.

Comment: It is not $3^{b^a}$ but $3^{ba}$ in fact , for $(b,a)=(3,2)$ we have $3^3\pmod{17}=10$ and $(3^3\pmod{17})^2=100=15\pmod{17}$. But $3^{3^2}=3^9=14\pmod{17}$. Instead $3^6=15\pmod{17}$